# RxJS observables catch errors without the error callback

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am wondering if there is a way to able to catch a subscribe error on an observable **without the error callback**?

For instance, you catch errors like this

```
 .subscribe({
 next: (obj) => {
    // Placeholder for code
 },

 // At the moment we need to include this error callback to show that an error has happened.
 // Forgetting to put this in means it 'bubbles' up so we cannot catch it and do anything with it.
 error: (e) => {
    this.showError(e.message);
 },
```

But if you look at the comment above, this is what happens when not including the callback.

**Forgetting to put this in means it 'bubbles' up so we cannot catch it and do anything with it.**

To be more explicit, even putting a `try-catch` around the method doesn't catch the error either.

I want to know this, because, if for some reason, a developer forgets to put the catch callback in, is there any way it can be caught? Because if not the error cannot be handled.

I think the issue is that as an observable is an async process, which happens on a new thread/task.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `catchError` within the observable, you can avoid needing the error callback. It's pretty common to handle the error within the stream itself, rather than on subscribe.

Something like

```
source.pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          console.error(err);
        }).subscribe(...)
```